# php how to shorten url - glob function

Tags: php

I use a glob function to list a folder items, the code below give me text like this "flash/movies", but I would like to trim the url to display only "movies". Can you help me what should I do ?

```
$dir = glob("flash/*");        
usort($dir, function($a, $b){
return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
    });
  foreach ($dir as $plk) { 
     echo '<h4>' . $plk . '</h4>';
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [basename()](http://php.net/basename) function. This returns the "trailing path component", which is the directory name that you are looking for.

For example:

```
echo '<h4>' . basename($plk) . '</h4>';
```